# Porque no recupera el valor del PLC desde RSLinx al cliente en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un cliente OPC el cual va recuperando el valor que van obteniendo del PLC mediante RSLinx pero cuando quiero obtener el valor me sale el siguiente error

```
PLCTAG_ERR_REMOTE_ERR (-29) - an unspecified or untranslatable remote error causes this.
```

De la siguiente manera estoy tratando de obtenerlo:

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try{
                //                      IP Address            AddrsDataFile
                var tagOpcServer = new Tag(new_IP, CpuType.SLC, "N7:30", DataType.Int64, 1);

                using (var client = new Libplctag()){
                    //Se añaden el tag que es el value a tomar de plc
                    client.AddTag(tagOpcServer);

                    //Se checa que el tag se alla añadido sino se vuelve a intentar
                    while (client.GetStatus(tagOpcServer) == Libplctag.PLCTAG_STATUS_PENDING){
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }

                    //En caso de que el status sea MALO se maneja el error
                    if (client.GetStatus(tagOpcServer) != Libplctag.PLCTAG_STATUS_OK){
                        status_1.Text = $"Error al configurar el estado interno de la etiqueta. Error{client.DecodeError(client.GetStatus(tagOpcServer))}\n";
                        //Console.WriteLine($"Error al configurar el estado interno de la etiqueta. Error{client.DecodeError(client.GetStatus(tagOpcServer))}\n");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Se ejecuta la lectura
                    var result = client.ReadTag(tagOpcServer, DataTimeout);

                    //Checamos si la operacion se completo
                    if (result != Libplctag.PLCTAG_STATUS_OK){
                        status_2.Text = $"ERROR: ¡No se pueden leer los datos! Se produjo un código de error {result} : {client.DecodeError(result)}\n";
                        //Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: ¡No se pueden leer los datos! Se produjo un código de error {result} : {client.DecodeError(result)}\n");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Se hace la conversion para que aparezcan los datos
                    //El cero corresponde al numero de memeoria  donde se obtendra el dato
                    var N7_0 = client.GetInt64Value(tagOpcServer, 0 * tagOpcServer.ElementSize); //Se multiplica con el tag

                    //Imprimir en un label
                    txtbx_val1.Text = Convert.ToString(N7_0);
                    //Console.WriteLine("N7_0: " + N7_0);  89 y 38
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Nota: La red cuenta con 2 firewalls, eso sera la causa del error?

Comment: Eso de los firewalls verifica con el área de redes

Comment: te recomiendo utilizar un otro tipo de Software que recolente los datos del PLC y que sea mas efectivo, por ejemplo KepServer y PI Server, yo utilizo esos dos sistemas y son una maravilla con C# ya que monitoreo PLCs que tiran datos por segundos.

Comment: -Pues lo que me han dicho es que para que pueda tener acceso y aparezcan los PLC en el RSLinx necesito loguearme al firewall y eso ya lo hice


                                                                               - Si vi que estaba el KepServer pero pues ya contaban con una licencia para el RSLinx y me dijeron que manejara ese